# Docker build throws 'Bad Gateway' error when getting the contatiner from "registry-1.docker.io"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run this command:

```
docker-compose pull --quiet --ignore-pull-failures
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Bad Gateway
```

This was working fine before but it suddenly stopped working.

Is this docker issue ?

Answer (score -1):

It happens sometimes!

Docker is not working at that time. You should restart your docker server. If you’re in windows and have a docker engine installed restart it manually by clicking on the docker icon on the bottom right then restart docker.

Or try the following command

```
service docker restart
docker pull...
```

If you are on linux based machine try the following command:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload #THIS IS RESCUE COMMAND…
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
$ sudo systemctl status docker
$ docker pull ...
```

**Note** : Try to log out and then login before executing the commands.

```
docker logout
docker login
```

you may also need to try connecting docker VM to direct internet connection without any firewall.

Comment: I am using ubuntu, can you please provide a link where I can reset firewall because restarting docker didn't fixed anything

Comment: I've added 3 Linux commands .. try them.

Comment: same thing : `Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Bad Gateway`

Comment: have you tried logout/login ?

Comment: I cant even login because I was using docker without an account. now even when I go to get started guid and try to run `.docker run --name repo 
alpine/git clone https://github.com/docker/getting-started.gi
t
docker cp repo:/git/getting-started/ .` I can't even login. I get the same gate way error

Comment: can you do this test "curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ && echo Works
" and tell me what the result you get back ?

Comment: This command `Works`

Comment: what is the result you got the curl?

Comment: I think it doesn't work:

`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--     0
`

Comment: The issue might be with your connection. Are you using any proxy ? can you go to dokcer and docker network check the DNS ? try put 8.8.8.8 in your DNS server.

Answer (score -2):

`sudo docker ...` works.

Maybe its firewall issue, but I am not sure